# Configure single gmail account for google docs edit in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, google-docs, alfresco-share

I am trying to configure a single gmail account to be used with google docs edit in Alfresco.
I added the following in alfresco-global.properties:

```
googledocs.googleeditable.enabled=true  
googledocs.username=username@gmail.com
googledocs.password=password
googledocs.application.name=Alfresco ECM system
googledocs.url=https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full
googledocs.downloadurl=https://docs.google.com/feeds/download
googledocs.spreadsheet.service.name=wise
googledocs.spreadsheet.downloadurl=https://spreadsheet.google.com/feeds/download
```

But, it again asks for authorization and to enter username, password, when I try editing in google docs.
Is there a way to configure the system, to directly go to the gmail account mentioned in the properties file?

Answer (score 1):

In order to enable Google Docs integration with Alfresco (hope you're talking about a > 4.0 Alfresco version) you need to:

- Open the Admin Console in Alfresco Share and then click Google Docs.
- Open the Google Docs page and click Edit.
- Set the Google Docs properties following directive from [this link](https://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/tasks/at-adminconsole-googledocs.html)

There is a [free Alfresco wiki PDF](http://wiki.alfresco.com/images/7/78/Getting_Started_with_Using_Google_Docs_with_Alfresco.pdf) to configure Google Docs.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, @Alc3mi5t, thanks for replying. Yes, I am using version 4.2.f. I had read about that, but my admin console doesn't show a Google Docs link.

Comment: hmm, if that's not the case, have you checked  your share-config-custom.xml file? you should enable google integration first.

Comment: I set the following to true in share-config-custom.xml :       <google-docs>
   <enabled>true</enabled> Is there anything else that needs to be modified?

Comment: well did u set up all the params in your `share-config-custom` file? googledocs.username and password? url?

Comment: I set them in the alfresco-global.properties, as mentioned above.

Comment: well, as mentioned in the pdf I linked earlier, you need to declare the aspect and enable googledocs integration, and update your googledocs parameters. That should work. Do you have 2-step verification on you Google account, or it's maybe a Google Apps account? Not sure if that could cause the issue

Comment: Yes, the aspect was already present in the share-config-custom.xml file and I had enabled google docs by setting it to true. It is not a google apps account but just a gmail account. Even I am confused, why it won't directly login. I don't see any error in the logs too.